# Using C# Reflection, how to get Object's properties and their values if that Object is a property of Object that is inside of the List

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to grab the value of a property of an ObjectB, which is a Property of ObjectA and ObjectA is inside of a `List<ObjectA>`

I browsed through some examplse, but could not find exactly what I need.

Here is what I'm looking for:

I have a class `MyScreenClass`, that has a `List<TicketReportPropertyEntity>`:

```
public class MyScreenClass
{
     public List<TicketReportPropertyEntity> TicketReportPropertyEntities{ get; set; } 
}
```

This is `TicketReportPropertyEntity` class that has another class which property I need to work with:

```
public class TicketReportPropertyEntity
{
    public decimal Amount{get;set;}
    public ReportPropertyEntity ReportProperty {get;set;}
}
```

This is `ReportPropertyEntity` class:

```
public class ReportPropertyEntity
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

What I need to do, is for each `TicketReportPropertyEntity` to get `Amount` from `TicketReportPropertyEntity` and `PropertyName` from `ReportPropertyEntity`.

The purpose is I need to compare the `PropertyName` with a given property and set the value to an `Amount`

So far, I only came up with the following:

```
foreach (var ticketReportEntity in mol.TicketReportPropertyEntities)
{
   PropertyInfo propertyInfo1 = ticketReportEntity.GetType().GetProperty("ReportProperty");
           //here I need to do all the logic
}
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you would have to get the child `PropertyInfo` of `ReportPropertyEntity.PropertyName` also. Then, proceed to check it against your target and set to amount to what you need.

```
MyScreenClass mol = new MyScreenClass{ TicketReportPropertyEntities = new List<TicketReportPropertyEntity>()};
mol.TicketReportPropertyEntities.Add(new TicketReportPropertyEntity
{
    ReportProperty = new ReportPropertyEntity
    {
        PropertyName = "CoolPropertyName"
    }
});

string propertyToSearchFor = "CoolPropertyName";

foreach (var ticketReportEntity in mol.TicketReportPropertyEntities)
{
    var type = ticketReportEntity.GetType();

    //Get PropertyInfo objects
    PropertyInfo reportProperty = type.GetProperty("ReportProperty");
    PropertyInfo reportPropertyName = typeof(ReportPropertyEntity).GetProperty("PropertyName");
    PropertyInfo amountProperty = type.GetProperty("Amount");

    //Get needed values
    ReportPropertyEntity reportPropertyValue = (ReportPropertyEntity)reportProperty.GetValue(ticketReportEntity);
    string reportPropertyNameValue = (string)reportPropertyName.GetValue(reportPropertyValue);

    //Check if change is required
    if (reportPropertyNameValue == propertyToSearchFor)
    {
        amountProperty.SetValue(ticketReportEntity, 123.45M);
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer yesterday, It really helped me. Will you be able to help me one more time? I have posted an update to my question right now. I have the explanation of what I'm looking for there?

Comment: @gene if you have a new question, please post it as a new question. Updating a current question with new requirements causes the question to not match the answers and goes against the strategy of the site. If you post a new question, I’ll check it out.

Comment: Thank's. Will do that

Comment: Here is the link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57222034/how-to-set-objects-properties-and-its-value-if-that-object-is-a-property-of-obj

Answer (score 1):

If you have to work with this two properties, and you have to store it in order to work with it, you could use:

```
List<TicketReportPropertyEntity> list = mol.TicketReportPropertyEntities;
List<keyValuePair<string, decimal>> values = 
   list.ToDictionary(element => element.ReportProperty.PropertyName, element => element.Amout).ToList();
```

Then, you will have a relationship between `Amout` and `PropertyName` properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
// get PropertyName from ReportPropertyEntity, and find it on TicketReportPropertyEntity
var myScreen = new MyScreenClass()
{
    TicketReportPropertyEntities = new List<UserQuery.TicketReportPropertyEntity>
    {
        new TicketReportPropertyEntity{
            Amount=1.0m,
            ReportProperty = new ReportPropertyEntity{PropertyName="Name"}
        }
    }

};
var reportPropertyAccessor = typeof(TicketReportPropertyEntity).GetProperty(nameof(TicketReportPropertyEntity.ReportProperty));
var propertyNameAccessor = typeof(ReportPropertyEntity).GetProperty(nameof(ReportPropertyEntity.PropertyName));
var amountAccessor = typeof(TicketReportPropertyEntity).GetProperty(nameof(TicketReportPropertyEntity.Amount));
typeof(TicketReportPropertyEntity).GetProperties().Dump();

foreach(object ticketReportEntity in myScreen.TicketReportPropertyEntities){
    var ticketReportPropertyEntity=reportPropertyAccessor.GetValue(ticketReportEntity);
    var pn = propertyNameAccessor.GetValue(ticketReportPropertyEntity);
    if("Name" == (string)pn){
        ticketReportPropertyEntity.Dump();
        amountAccessor.SetValue(ticketReportEntity,2.0m);
    }
}
```